# Потеря данных в потоках? Запись данных из разных потоков

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

Потеря данных при сохранении из разных потоков будет или нет в следущих сценариях

- запись в разные таблицы
- запись в одну таблицу

> Приведите подробности, а лучше код.

Запись в одну таблицы:

```cs
static string connString = "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQL;Initial Catalog=Database;";

void Thread1() 
{ 
   var conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
   // команда записи в одну таблицу
   var com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 ... 
}

void Thread2() 
{ 
   var conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
   // команда записи в ту же самую таблицу
   var com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 ...
```

Запись в разные таблицы:

```cs
static string connString = "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQL;Initial Catalog=Database;";

void Thread1() 
{ 
   var conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
   // команда записи в одну таблицу
   var com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 ... 
}

void Thread2() 
{ 
   var conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
   // запись в другую таблицу
   var com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table2 ...
}
```

Comment: Если писать правильно, потери данных не будет. Если неправильно, то будет. Количество потоков при этом не важно. (Хотя правильный код для многопоточного случая может быть не таким, как для однопоточного.)

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, на него невозможно дать обоснованный ответ. Приведите подробности, а лучше код.

Comment: Код добавил, но как и думал, бесполезно. Еще какие-то подробности надо добавить?

Comment: Почему бы вам просто не воспользоваться EF?

Comment: Не знаю как через EF решить задачу. Никогда не работал с EF.

Answer (score 4):

В приведенных вами примерах кода не будет потери данных, ни при записи в одну таблицу, ни при записи в разные таблицы.

SQL Server обеспечивает целостность при одновременной записи данных за счет блокировок.

В первом случае тот поток, который первый начнет запись поставит блокировку на таблицу, и не отпустит ее до завершения транзакции. Если явное управление транзакциями не используется - то SQL Server сам обернет в транзакцию ваш INSERT.

Второй поток будет ждать особождения блокировки, и уже только потом запишет свои данные.

Т.е. по сути SQL Server проследит за записью данных и не допустит действительно "одновременной" вставки.

При записи в разные таблицы потоки вообще не пересекаются по данным, и никаких потерь тем более не будет.